# angle of intersection between two lines

Tags: calculus

Show that the angle between the tangent at any point $p$ and the line joining $p$ to the origin $O$ is same at all the points of the curve $\log(x^2+y^2)=c\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$ where $c$ is any arbitrary constant .

Answer (score 1):

Denote $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$ as the polar coordinates, then the given equation
$$\log(x^2+y^2)=c\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right) \implies 2\log r = c \theta \implies r = \mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac{c}2 \theta \right)$$
is readily recognized as the logarithmic spiral.

The requested ["constant angle" property is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral#Properties) and easily proven, see for example [Eq.(5) of this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html).

If one wants to start from scratch and deal with the equation in the given form, then read on.

---

The title of the original post "angle of intersection between two lines", suggests that the asker was having difficulties determining the angle between the tangent direction $(1, y')$ and radial direction $(x,y)$.

The standard way to do this is to consider the inner product. Denote $\alpha$ as the angle between the two lines (or local angle between two local directional vectors), then the task is to show
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{ \text{inner product} }{ \text{product of norms} } =\frac{ (1, y') \bullet (x,y) }{ \lVert (1,y')\rVert\,\cdot\, \lVert(x,y) \rVert} \overset{?}{=} \text{constant}$$

Here $\displaystyle y' \equiv \frac{ \mathrm{d} y }{ \mathrm{d}x}$. Let's take the implicit derivative on both sides of the entire give equation.

\begin{gather*}
&\frac1{x^2 + y^2} \left( 2x + 2yy'\right) = c \frac1{ 1 + (y/x)^2} \frac{ y' x - y }{ x^2 } \\
&\implies 2\left( x + yy'\right) = c(y' x - y) \implies y' = \frac{ 2x + cy }{ cx - 2y} \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{gather*}
This gives the inner product as 
$$(1, y') \bullet (x,y) = x+yy' = x + y\frac{ 2x + cy }{ cx - 2y} = \frac{  x(cx - 2y) + y (2x + cy) }{ cx - 2y} = \frac{  c(x^2 + y^2)}{ cx - 2y} \tag{2} \label{2}$$

Now, also make use of Eq.\eqref{1} to obtain the product of the norms:
\begin{gather*}
\lVert(1,y')\rVert\,\cdot\, \lVert(x,y)\rVert = \sqrt{ \left( 1+(y')^2 \right) \left( x^2 + y^2\right)} \\ 
\text{with} \quad 1+(y')^2 = \frac{ (cx - 2y)^2 + (2x + cy)^2 }{ (cx - 2y)^2 } \implies 1+(y')^2 = \frac{ (c^2 + 4)( x^2 + y^2) }{ (cx - 2y)^2 } \\
\implies \lVert(1,y')\rVert\,\cdot\, \lVert (x,y) \rVert = \sqrt{(c^2 + 4)}\frac{ x^2 + y^2 }{ |cx - 2y| } \tag{3} \label{3}
\end{gather*}

Finally, putting Eq.\eqref{2} and Eq.\eqref{3} together we have
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{ \pm c }{ \sqrt{(c^2 + 4)} } \tag{4} \label{4}$$
where the sign is determined by the sign of $cx - 2y$.

We know that a cosine flipping sign means the angle flips to its complement to $\pi$. That is, Eq.\eqref{4} correctly gives the cosine of a **oriented** angle of a constant magnitude between two oriented directions.$~~$***Q.E.D.***